# Counting instances of a string in a table Java/Processing

Tags: java, processing

New to coding so looking for some help.
I have a csv dataset which contains a couple of columns and a few thousand rows. The rows are grouped by an ID and I'm trying to count how many instances of each ID number there are in the CSV.

i.e. 100 fall under ID number 1, 210, under number 2 etc.

The data is loaded as a table into processing, is there some kind of while/for/if loop or anything I can use to simply count how many times a certain string appears in the file?

TIA

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather, the way to go would be with a `HashMap<String,Integer>` or even `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` if you're sure the ids will always be numeric and fit inside an Integer.

The following code assumes there's a Collection of `ids` called `listOfIds`.
It will traverse this list and check if we have any value stored for the key `id` in our `HashMap`.

If not, it will store the value `1` in there, symbolizing we have found once this id.

Otherwise, if it's not the first time we have found this id, we retrieve the current value and increment it by one.

```
Map<String,Integer> mapOfIds = new HashMap<>();
for(String id: listOfIds) {
    Integer currentValue = mapOfIds.get(id) == null ? 1 : mapOfIds.get(id) + 1;
    mapOfIds.put(id,currentValue);
}
```